# CakePHP 3 force logout at login

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm using CakePHP in version 3. How can I force an automatic logout from CakePHP website on one device if user wants to log in on the other device? I want the user to have a possibility to only log in on one device at one time.